# Fragment null must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am not able to figure out why my app crashes when getSupportFragmentManager() is called.I have used similar code in other apps to create alert dialogs without any issues.please help!

```
DialogFragment df = new DialogFragment(){

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.addincome,null);
            builder.setView(view);
            //capture
            final EditText amountEditText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_amount);
            final EditText descriptionEditText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_description);
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,null);
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    newIncome.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(amountEditText.getText().toString()));
                    newIncome.setDescription(descriptionEditText.getText().toString());
                    user.incomes.add(newIncome);
                    HashMap<String,User> modified = new HashMap<>();
                    modified.put(uid,user);
                    rootref.setValue(modified);
                }
            });
            return builder.create();
        }
    };
    df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"addIncome");
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `DialogFragment` is an anonymous class, and in Java anonymous classes can only be instantiated by parent classes: the `new DialogFragment()` is in fact `this.new DialogFragment()`. Apparently, when `FragmentManager` tries to recreate your `DialogFragment` upon a configuration change, it can't, since it doesn't have the access to the instance of the parent class. The solution would be to either declare a `static` subclass of `DialogFragment`, or to declare a top-level subclass of `DialogFragment`, and use it instead of the anonymous class.

Comment: And it must also have a default (no-argument) constructor

Comment: Is it possible for me to create a context containing this and use context.new DialogFragment() ??

Comment: And I am sorry for being unable to upvote your answer, my reputation is too low....thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know you have done this step but just asking did you tried to rebuild your APK?because if this code works in other applications then their must be some .classes issue.

Comment: I did try...still didn't work...I think the other applications have a @suppresslint option but i'm a beginner and don't know how to add or check for this option

Comment: You can disable lint in android studio by writing following in your build.gradle

lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }

Answer (score 0):

check which type of Fragment you have in your imports whether your'e using android.support.v4.app.Fragment or android.os.Fragment.

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;